# Find LCM of two numbers

Tags: c++, lcm

The program should first ask that I enter how many times it should ask me for two numbers. After I give two numbers it should find the LCM of them and do the operation as many times as I entered in the beginning.

It opens and waits for me to give the numbers and does nothing.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int ile ;
int grupa1, grupa2 ;
int wynik ;
int dzielnik = 0;

int main()
{
    cin >> ile ;
    for (int i=0; i <= ile ; i++ )
    {
        cin >> grupa1 >> grupa2 ;
        do
        {
            do
            {
                dzielnik ++ ;
              } while ((dzielnik % grupa1 != 0 && dzielnik % grupa2 !=0 )     || dzielnik < grupa1 + grupa2) ;

                if (dzielnik % grupa1 == 0 && dzielnik % grupa2 == 0 )
            {
            grupa1 = grupa1 / dzielnik ;
            grupa2 = grupa2 / dzielnik ;
        }
        else if (dzielnik >= grupa1 + grupa2)
        {
            wynik = grupa1 * grupa2 ;
            cout << wynik ;
        }
    }
    while (wynik == grupa1 * grupa2) ;
    dzielnik = 0;
}
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`cout` is buffered and won't display anything until it has 1) been provided with enough data or 2) been flushed.

Change this line:

```
cout << wynik ;
```

To this:

```
cout << wynik << endl;
```

And you should see some output.

---

Also, you should consider fixing your indentation.  Currently it's very misleading.  The main `for` lines up with a `while` and the internal `do` lines up with an `else if`.